# Best practices in Server side validation of In app purchase in iOS

Tags: ios, transactions, in-app-purchase, payment, storekit

We are using server side validation of the payment like so -

1. User makes payment.
2. Store kit API sends transaction receipt to App.
3. App sends base64 encoded transaction receipt to our server.
4. Our server calls https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt and validates the transaction recept.
5. User is marked as paid.

For a particular user, we didn't get the transaction receipt at the server, due to which the receipt couldn't be verified. We are guessing something went wrong in steps 2 and 3.
If there were connection problems at the time of sending receipt to server, the app retries again on subsequent app resume.

Now we have one missing transaction receipt and an angry user. How do you suggest we go forward? How can we prevent this in future? Are there any guidelines or best practices that we can follow to prevent such situation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my experience, the likely issues are

- The base64 data got url-encoded along the way and so + and / got messed up - replace these with safer characters before transfer
- The whole transaction is bogus.

The way to check for the second case is to look at your account and see if there is a matching purchase record. Unfortunately, the web site can be a bit difficult to review unless you have a low purchase volume.

The are two things you need in your code to correctly handle errors on your server or on, if it happens, Apple's end.

1. Do not call finishTransaction: until you have successfully communicated with your server (it wouldn't help in this case but worth noting)
2. Have a "Reload Purchases" button or action that calls restoreCompletedTransactions: on the SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue.  For non-consumable/entitlement objects, this will resend all transactions with receipts that can be re-verified on your server.

If the problem you are facing is with non-consumables/entitlements, then the second item is the way out.

Comment: Is Non-renewing subscriptions restored with second method?

Comment: The base64 url-encoding thing is taken care of, so we know for sure that is not the case. Also, the fix that you suggested - (1), we are handling it in a different way, if we haven't successfully communicated with server, we put it in a secure local storage and call our servers at given trigger points. So that is ruled out too. What other suggestions do you have?   
Thanks